# Adding dynamically to multidimensional array javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var oparea = [];
var mainarr_index = 0;

$("input.oparea-name").each(function(opera_key) {                                  
    var name_oparea = $(this);
    oparea[mainarr_index]['maincat']['name'] = name_oparea.val(); //Add to array

    $(subcats).each(function(index) { 
        oparea[mainarr_index]['subcat']['name'].push(name_subcat);
    }

    mainarr_index++;
}
```

**The result I want:**

```
oparea[0]['maincat']['name'] = 'name of oparea1';
oparea[0]['maincat']['subcat'] = array('name' => array('subcatname1', 'subcatname2'));

oparea[1]['maincat']['name'] = 'name of oparea2';
oparea[1]['maincat']['subcat'] = array('name' => array('subcatname1', 'subcatname2'));
```

//etc etc

The result I get in console is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'maincat' of undefined

Of course it's undefined, therefore I want to define it ;-)

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: What is `mainarr_index`?

Comment: Sorry it's just a counter.. I'll update question

Comment: It's better to use `push` method instead direct element access

Comment: I don't understand how to achieve that . It's very important that key for opera['subcat'] and opera['maincat'] are equal. If I do a push on the maincat they won't be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the property of an object if there's no object there to begin with. And you can't push onto an array if the array hasn't been created yet (I suspect you're used to PHP, which will fill these things in automatically when necessary).

And you can use `.push` to add the new object to the array, instead of using the `oparea_index` variable.

```
$("input.oparea-name").each(function(opera_key) {                                  
    var name_oparea = $(this);
    var new_oparea = {
        maincat: {
            name: name_oparea.val()
        },
        subcat: {
            name: []
        }
    };

    $(subcats).each(function(index) { 
        new_oparea.subcat.name.push(name_subcat);
    }

    oparea.push(new_oparea);
}
```

Comment: Aha. Thanks a lot! And yes, you're susipicion about PHP was correct :-)

Comment: FYI, if you turn on warnings in PHP, it will complain about code like that.

Comment: Where does `name_subcat` come from?

Comment: name_subcat is supposed to be given by dynamically created input elements under the opareas. I could not paste in the whole code here though :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var oparea = [];
$("input.oparea-name").each(function(opera_key) {                                  
    var name_oparea = $(this);
    if(!oparea[mainarr_index]){
        oparea[mainarr_index]={};
    }
    if(!oparea[mainarr_index]['maincat']){
        oparea[mainarr_index]['maincat']={};
    }
    oparea[mainarr_index]['maincat']['name'] = name_oparea.val(); //Add to array

    $(subcats).each(function(index) { 
        if(!oparea[mainarr_index]){
            oparea[mainarr_index]={};
        }
        if(!oparea[mainarr_index]['subcat']){
            oparea[mainarr_index]['subcat']={};
        }
        if(!oparea[mainarr_index]['subcat']['name']){
            oparea[mainarr_index]['subcat']['name']=[];
        }
        oparea[mainarr_index]['subcat']['name'].push(name_subcat);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess this would work also, but I think Barmars solution is "cleaner" (eaiser to read and understand the code).